# cone that holds 2 ounces

Tags: volume

if cutting a central cross section of a cone yields an angle of 22 degrees at its point, what does the height have to be to hold 2 ounces or 3.6 cubic inches of water?  I believe the answer should be done by solving for the integral of the circle area over the height.

Comment: You should be able to avoid integration by using trig functions. Use your angle to find the ratio of the height to the base's radius (say $2:1$). Once you have this, set this up as $x*2x$ and let it equal $3V$, where $V$ is volume.

Comment: You only need integration if you want to derive the formula for the volume of the cone. Otherwise, you can just use the formula.